# counter marker css not working on mac safari

Tags: css

```html
  <style>
    #top-menu li::marker {
     
      content: counter(list-item, decimal-leading-zero) ".";
      color: #848484;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
   #top-menu .current-menu-item::marker{
      color: #FF6436;
    }
    
    .menu-item a:hover::marker {
        color: #FF6436;
    }
    </style>

    <div id=top-menu>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Service</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        
        </ul>
      </div>
```

There is a menu list in WordPress.
To number the menu list, I use CSS pseudo classes.
For Chrome and Firefox everything works fine.
But Safari does not want to.
Who can help please.

site https://hypefactory.dvasyl.com/technology/

Comment: What's your relevant HTML? From the documentation at MDN: "*[It works on any element or pseudo-element set to `display: list-item`, such as the `<li>` and `<summary>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker).*" Also - while you've shared your CSS - the posting of your "*[mcve] code*" is required on Stack Overflow, see also "*[something in my web site...doesn't work. Can I just link to it?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/82548)*"

Comment: I share the code with ease.
How do I pull the entire Wordpress site here? I left a link to the site.

Comment: Just the *minimal* amount of your HTML, so a sample of the HTML for the menu you're having problems with would be enough; we definitely don't want - or need - the "entire Wordpress site."

Comment: You're right!
I made it in HTML.
Please help me to make it work in Safari.

Comment: I wonder why you don't use an `<ol>` with `list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero`?

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to use the right tool for the job. In this case, since you seem to want to have an ordered list, so the `ol` element is custom-made for that requirement. Add the appropriate `list-style-type` to the `li`'s style, and you're good to go.

```html
<style>
  #top-menu li {
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  }
  
  #top-menu li::marker {
    color: #848484;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  #top-menu .current-menu-item::marker {
    color: #FF6436;
  }
  
  .menu-item a:hover::marker {
    /* Note this won't change the color of the marker on 
       the li because you're targeting the a element. You'd 
       need to use .menu-item::marker:has(a:hover) (if the 
       browser has support) or just .menu-item:hover::marker 
       since they'd hover over the li as well as the anchor, 
       presumably */
    color: #FF6436;
  }
</style>

<div id=top-menu>
  <ol>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Service</li>
    <li>Contact</li>

  </ol>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you have to get creative and use the `::before` pseudo-element instead of the `::marker` pseudo-element

```html
<style>
  #top-menu ul {
    counter-reset(list-item);
  }
  
  #top-menu li {
    counter-increment(list-item);
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  #top-menu li::before {
    content: counter(list-item, decimal-leading-zero) ".";
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    color: #848484;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  #top-menu .current-menu-item::before {
    color: #FF6436;
  }
  
  .menu-item a:hover::before {
    /* Note this won't change the color of the marker on 
       the li because you're targeting the a element. See above. */
    color: #FF6436;
  }
</style>

<div id=top-menu>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Service</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```